# best way to pass data to different Pages using Hooks in a react native app?

Tags: react-native, geolocation, react-hooks, react-native-maps

I have a simple RN app that gets my current location:

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
```

Using useEffect, I fire a method called requestLocationPermission to check Permissions and then get my current location.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // console.log('is this working');
    requestLocationPermission();
  }, []);


async function requestLocationPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        title: 'Location Permission',
        message: 'This app needs access to your location',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('You can use the location');
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
          //  useCoordinates = position;
          console.log('hey man', position);
        },
        error => {
          // See error code charts below.
          console.log(error.code, error.message);
        },
        {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000},
      );
    } else {
      console.log('Location permission denied', granted);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
}
```

I'd like to use useState to store the location so that when I navigate to the page that contains MapView, the current location/marker is updated using the proper coordinates.

Currently, the page that contains the map:

```
const About: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 47.48934444614,
            longitude: 227.004444388,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
          showsCompass={true}>

          <Marker
            title={"house"}
            coordinate={{latitude: 47.48934444614, longitude: 227.004444388}}
          />
        </MapView>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

export default About
```

Is there a way this can be done only using hooks?  Or will I need to use Redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

create a context

`const LocationContext = React.createContext({latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0});`

the wrap your parent component with the provider -

```
<LocationContext.Provider value={/* value from geo location */}>
    {/* child view */}
</LocationContext.Provider>
```

the child views can use the consumer to get values

```
 <LocationContext.Consumer>
      {({latitude, longitude}) => (
        <View> ... </View>
      )}
</LocationContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: Sorry about the late response.  This is exactly what I was looking for.